# Why would bootstrap dropdown nav button work in all screen sizes except for one?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this site here (using bootstrap 4.1.2):

https://secure2.convio.net/cco/site/SPageServer/?pagename=RFL_NW_QC_Impact

And for some reason the dropdown button in the top right works on mobile, and on most of desktop but screen sizes between 786px to 991px won't work, any smaller or larger and it works perfectly.

Someone else created this page so I'm trying to help fix the issue but I can't pinpoint what's causing it. Doesn't seem like a situation where `z-index` would need to be used because it can still be clicked it just doesn't expand.

I checked the console and fixed the errors that came up but that still didn't solve the issue. Normally it's on mobile where I have this problem because something is overlapping the button but it doesn't seem to be the problem this time.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening/closing the menu is done by two custom functions contained in a `<script>` tag placed in `<head>`, on lines `187` and `195`, respectively.

Each of them has the entire body of code wrapped in a condition:

```
if ($(document).width() <= 768) {
 ...
}
```

Change both conditions to `if ($(document).width() <= 992)`.

---

You also have another, potentially bigger problem:

On line `391`, you have `…</script>`, ending the current script abruptly, which is a sign that code was copy/pasted from a browser source code, without properly viewing the entire source code (when viewing large chunks of code, Chrome shows the first `n` lines and hides the rest under `…`, which acts as a link to the rest of the code). I'm surprised your console isn't bleeding heavily.

The proper way to retrieve the source of a particular tag is to right-click on it in dev-tools and select "Edit as html". In the opening editor window, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the entire contents of that tag.

Comment: thank you Andrei! I'll have a chat with the person who created this to see where they pulled code from. I'll also update the js from 768 to 992, I didn't even realize that was custom I thought it was bootstrap default but after reviewing it I see it's referencing specific classes that someone else created.

Comment: The drop down button now works! thank you so much. I'll also review how this was built with my colleague. The only front end developer we had has left so I'm trying to help as much as I can but I'm by no means an expert, so I really appreciate your time with this. thank you again!